# Java Regular expression for 1=1

Tags: java, regex

I need to look for java regex pattern that finds input string in the format of 1=1 where prefix of "=" should have same count of digits with the suffix. Also here both prefix & suffix values should be the same like 1=1, 11=11, 223=223. Values like 1=2, 3=22, 33=22 should not match the pattern

Can we have a general pattern to satisfy above rules.

Comment: You can also check if `str.split("=")[0].equals(str.split("=")[1])`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a back  reference:

```
(\d+)=\1\b
```

of course, in java you need to escape the back slashes:

```
"(\\d+)=\\1\\b"
```

Comment: this might give problems at 

7=77

as it sees it as 7=7

i don't know if author see this as a problem tough

Answer (score 3):

You can check without regex too.

```
 String exp="lhs=rhs";
 if(exp.split("=")[0].equals(exp.split("=")[1])){
        System.out.println("true");
 }else{
        System.out.println("false");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [capture groups and backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html):

```
^(\\d+)=\\1$
```

[The anchors are to prevent anything else matching]

Perhaps a more fool proof expression would be:

```
^\\s*(\\d+)\\s*=\\s*\\1\\s*$
```

Which takes ignores eventual whitespaces which could otherwise make things not work as expected. Of course, this now depends on whether you are saying, for example that `1 =1` is a valid input string.

---

A more general expression could be:

```
^\\s*(.+?)\\s*=\\s*\\1\\s*$
```

Where you'll be able to compare any string before an equal sign. `.+?` matches any character  until an equal sign.